# How to install Cave Story?

Tags: software-installation

So I've downloaded the `.tar.gz` file for Cave Story, and since I'm somewhat new to Ubuntu, I have no idea how to install it.

I tried the commands suggested at [How do I install a .tar.gz (or .tar.bz2) file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25961/how-to-install-a-tar-gz-or-tar-bz2-file), but no dice.

My most successful attempt was `make config.dat`, which spat out a different error than make all the other files. So I assume that's what I should be going with?

It says:

```
"make: *** No rule to make target `config.dat'. Stop."
```

Do I type something else in?

Comment: put the `cavestory.tar.gz` download link.

Comment: Cave Story is not usually a source distributed software. The .tar.gz probably contains binary software (probably from Humble Bundle or similar). Therefore, the linked other question is likely to be irrelevant.

Answer (score 2):

Is late a lot but here is your answer. From [the download page on cavestory.org](http://www.cavestory.org/download/cave-story.php) download this version: Doukutsu Linux Port by Simon Parzer and Peter Mackay

1. Extract the file in Downloads.
2. Open the terminal(<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>) and type: `cd ~/Downloads/linuxDoukutsu-1.01`
3. Type `./doukutsu`

It will open the game. To exit press exit.

Answer (score 0):

I could not execute the binary versions that [the previous answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/959737/527764) mentioned.

However, was able compile this version and it worked!

https://github.com/coringao/cavestory-nx

Its README contains instructions of how to compile it:

> On Debian/Ubuntu/GNU/Linux you can get all necessary packages by typing:
>
> ```
> sudo apt install cmake libpng-dev libsdl2-dev libsdl2-mixer-dev
> ```
>
> When all these dependencies are installed to start compiling the game. To create the archive binary, do it from the source directory.
>
> Creating directory and accessing:
>
> ```
> mkdir -p build && cd build
> ```
>
> Starting to build:
>
> ```
> cmake ..
> ```
>
> Starting compilation:
>
> ```
> make
> ```
>
> Running the game:
>
> ```
> ../cavestory-nx
> ```
>
> Removing the build directory and the binary:
>
> ```
> rm -rf build cavestory-nx
> ```